# How to find tension in the string given in the question below?

Tags: classical-mechanics

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ihu6.jpg) Only a part is needed. Thanks.

Comment: Ouch, my neck. Couldn't you have rotated that image before you uploaded it?

Answer (score 1):

Some trigonometry is required, but the gist of it is that because the particle is at rest (not accelerating) the *horizontal component* of the tension in $BP$ is equal to the horizontal component of the tension in $AP$. All you have to do is figuring out all the angles involved and decompose all the forces correctly.